# Best practices in a laravel & vuejs application authentication and routing

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am going to build an SPA with Laravel and Vuejs.
Since this will be my first large application using this combination, I had some questions that I wanted to ask because I didn't find a clear answer:

1: Authentication. When searching on the internet I found a lot of topics about authenticating with a JWT token. What is the advantage of using such a token instead of normal authentication? If I authenticate in the "normal" way and check for auth()->check() in my application I have the same result no?

2: Routing. Since I will be using Vue-router, my application will have Vue and Laravel based routes. Does that mean that the Laravel routes are defined as API calls? And should they be in the API route group then? Or are they just normal routes that belong to the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. JWT tokens have some advantages over traditional session base authentication.  For example you don store session data on server and save server resources , jwt tokens are available in your request amoung multiple servers and so on...
   For further reading check this article :
   https://float-middle.com/json-web-tokens-jwt-vs-sessions/

2.Yes you should use laravel routes as restful apis